# Question about Swami Ayyappa and Mahishi's time period

Tags: asuras, ayyappa

I have few confusions about Swami Ayyappa story - In movies it is shown that when Ayyappa goes to forest to bring Tiger milk that is the time he kills Mahishi. But King of Pandalam is of this yuga (may be few centuries back) so does it mean Mahishi was also of this yuga?

Was Mahishi alive till few centuries back or can anyone tell the time period according to real story?

Comment: The story of ayyappa happened a few centuries ago. There was a sufi friend to ayyappa and turned to a devotee called vavaru. This indicates that it is not before muslims entered our country.

Comment: Actually, there are two Ayyappas:- the first one is well-known god and second one is lesser-known historical hero and his real name is Arya Kerala Varman. Vavar lived at the era of Arya Kerala Varman and we mistook him with Ayyappa Swamy.

Comment: Ayyappa swamy's father is a Pandya King. Mahishi Samhara is happened to Puranic era and also none of asuras exist at Kali Yuga, expect Kali Purusha.